# Vertical Sync on MBP

Tags: screen, gpu

On PCs you could easily configure the Vertical Sync setting from NVidia control panel, how can you enable/disable vertical sync in OS X?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OSX, Veritical Sync is called Beam Sync

Running the command `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver Compositor -dict deferredUpdates 0` should do it for you, but you may need to reboot. Replace the 0 with 1 to re-enable.

You should also be able to do this by downloading [this prefpane](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) and looking under "System". Another way is to use Quartz Debug to disable it, but it seems like that has become harder to run on Lion & ML.

Comment: I love Mac, but life would be so much easier if they'd use standard terminology. Reminds me of when IBM insisted on calling pixels "PELs."